# what are these different in array initializing in c?

Tags: c, arrays

My struct is as follow.

```
typedef struct user {
   char *name;
   int age;
} User;
```

Now when I am creating an array, I wonder what is the different between below both statments.

```
User users[10];
```

vs

```
User users[10] = {};
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-c?rq=1

Comment: If `users` has static linkage, there is no difference. If it is an automatic variable, the former's content is indeterminate, the latter is zero-filled.

Comment: The latter is invalid in C.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY true that. I assumed the OP was using the GNU initialization extension.

Answer (score 0):

The first (User users[10];) do not erase the flash or memory so it is possibel that you have things on this memory from the Programm befor

Comment: What is "flasch" (!?)

Comment: sry i mean flash its a kind of memory often used for the programmmemory in microcontroller

Comment: Variables will never be directly in flash memory.